# RegEx that matches letters and numbers together or letters only

Tags: javascript, ios, regex

Trying to build a regex that matches these criteria but couldn't find a clue for that:

1) letters and numbers **together** only

2) **or** letters only

3) no numbers alone allowed

4) the whole string length must be between 3 and 7 characters.

5) spaces allowed at any position (start, middle or end) of the string at the same time not allowing numbers alone like in 33 33, but spaces alone are not (like when you enter 3 empty spaces)

example matches:

1w1

e3e

wer

123 (doesn't match)

11e

e11

111 33r

eee eee

eee e33

Comment: What's your problem with your current regex?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based upon your rules, you can use this regex,

```
^(?![\d ]*$)[a-zA-Z0-9 ]{3,7}$
```

[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/J7sUl7/2/)

Comment: it doesn't satisfy rule number 3 and 5, i.e. this string must not match: 555 55

Comment: @JAHelia: It does. It is rejecting the string if all characters are digits. And also satisfying rule 5. [Check my demo](https://regex101.com/r/LHTrVh/1/)

Comment: in case there is a space between these digits it satisfies it like in 44 44, where the requirement that 44 44 must not match

Comment: @JAHelia: I thought allowing space breaks the rule where only digits are present but it can be easily handled. Let me update.

Comment: @JAHelia: Updated my answer. Now strings having only numbers and/or spaces will be rejected.

Comment: Isn't that easier to do `(?![\d ]+$)` instead of `(?! *\d+( *\d+)* *$)`?

Comment: @revo: You're right and simple and good suggestion. Probably I was overthinking. Let me update. But one point is not clear. Whether a string all having space is allowed or not. Although it shouldn't but rule number 5 says spaces allowed anywhere. So following rule 5. All spaces can be allowed.

Comment: @PushpeshKumarRajwanshi the regex works in all cases except in the empty space case: when you enter 3 empty spaces it matches but it breaks rule number 1 and 2 where the allowed only are letters and numbers or letters

Comment: First two rules specified that input string should be letters or digits. Spaces are optional.

Comment: @JAHelia: Ok sure, this is what revo also pointed out, that only spaces should not match, which wasn't very clear from your rules but now it seems clear. Let me update the regex.

Comment: @PushpeshKumarRajwanshi I'm sorry for ambiguity, I have edited rule number 5 for the case of empty space

Comment: @revo: Yes revo you're right. Spaces are optional and hence only space should be rejected.

Comment: @JAHelia: Please check my updated answer. Now it rejects the string containing only digits or spaces or mix of both. Let me know if for any of the samples it doesn't work.

Comment: @PushpeshKumarRajwanshi the update works fine, but there is one more rule, which it must not allow special characters like (.%$%&*, etc...) only a-z A-Z, the requirement in rule 1 states 'letters' but not special characters

Comment: @JAHelia: This character set `[a-zA-Z0-9 ]` already doesn't allow any special characters and only allows alphanumeric and space within allowed charset.